# Running Weblogic inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, weblogic12c

So I am running weblogic and deploying a webapp from inside eclipse.  Where are the jsp files located?  How can I change the JSP without a restart/redeploy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying the project directly from eclipse then you don't need to go anywhere.
You just open and edit that file into eclipse and save, it will automatically reflect all the changes.

**[image: Note:]** It will work if and only if you have selected **Build Automatically** in the project option at the top of your eclipse.

Comment: And you can find your deployed application in the following directory-
D:\ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\domains\your_domain_name\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\your_app_name